# Why are many different ways to dispatch with abstract types in Julia ? and what is the difference between them?

Tags: julia

What is the essential difference between those three different ways of declaring a function with abstract type in julia ?

```
Base.zero(::AbstractZero) = Zero()
```

```
Base.zero(::Type{<:AbstractZero}) = Zero()
```

```
Base.zero(::Type{T}) where T <: AbstractZero = Zero()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Base.zero(::Type{<:AbstractZero}) = Zero()
```

and

```
Base.zero(::Type{T}) where T <: AbstractZero = Zero()
```

are almost the same. In this case they are the same.

The difference would be if you wanted to use `T` in the definition of the function somewhere (as in the first case it is undefined).

To be precise:

```
Base.zero(::Type{<:AbstractZero}) = Zero()
```

expands to:

```
zero(::Type{var"#s1"} where var"#s1"<:AbstractZero)
```

but the scoping difference is neglibible.

---

Now the difference between:

```
Base.zero(::AbstractZero) = Zero()
```

and

```
Base.zero(::Type{<:AbstractZero}) = Zero()
```

is that the first dispatches on an object of a given type, and the second dispatches on a type itself. Here is an MWE:

```
julia> f(::Integer) = "integer passed"
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(::Type{<:Integer}) = "integer type passed"
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> f(1)
"integer passed"

julia> f(Int)
"integer type passed"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
Base.zero(::T) where T <: AbstractZero = Zero()
```

similar to the first variant with the same explanation as @Bogumił Kamiński gave, that is, if you want to use the type `T` within your function, that actually called the function.